# Faster way to search and change data in a large associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very large associative array (~5.000.000 elements), with a simmilar structure:

```
$largeArray = array(
      '1'  => array(
          'type'       => char(1),
          'o_id'       => int(11),
          'p_id'       => int(11),
          'parent'     => int(11),
          'linked'     => int(11),
          'name'       => string,
          'alternate'  => string(long),
          'extratags'  => string(in hcode format),
          'deep'       => int(1),
          'children'   => int(7),
          'fcode'      => char(3)
      ),
      ....
 )
```

**NOTE:** The keys in $largeArray are not incremented one by one, they are each a unique int that is 11 bytes long.

I want to parse through this array, and check if each sub arrays `linked` property is 0 or not. If it is not 0, it means that it points to another sub array of `$largeArray`, with the corresponding key. If this is the case, the two data's must be merged (it doesn't matter now, how are they merged), so that one of the keys will be deleted from the array. The links are one way only, so for example if A is linked to B, B is not linked back to A. It is possible that B is also linked to a C, so the merging operation is done recursively, like this:

```
 mergeTwoIds($id1, $id2) {
     if ($largeArray[$id2]['linked'] != 0) mergeTwoIds($id2, $largeArray[$id2]['linked']);
 }
```

When the two arrays are merged, IF the `children` property of the later deleted array is not 0, I have to change every other sub array which has as a `parent` the later deleted array, to a new value. To do this, right now I go through the whole array, and check each ones `parent` property, and if I found the deleted sub arrays id in it, I change it. This is very slow. I don't know exactly how many linked sub arrays are there in the dataset, but to do this for each merging, it takes around 30 secs to perform. The script I run to do this operation, parsed around 40000 children in 5480 secs, and estimates that until completition there is another 575707 secs left. This is a very rough estimate, because I don't know the exact number of linked children, thus I can't calculate exactly.

Would there be a faster way of achieving the desired result? (Changing the `parent` of each element with a specific `parent` value)

**NOTE2:** This is a one time run script, the memory of the server I am working on, is purely dedicated to this operation, and the server has 36GB RAM, and PHP is allowed to use up 26GB of it.

Comment: The fastest way is probably to make the changes at source (e.g. on the database if it comes from a database), before you ever load that volume of data into PHP

Comment: Not possible, the data is not stored in a database yet, it is stored as a json file of (1GB). I could load it up like this to a mysql database though, and make the changes there, do you think it would be faster that way? The intended destination of the data is a mysql database anyways.

Comment: Well if its a ONE-OFF execution. Speed is surely not as important as Accuracy